# Is this assertation in thread3 guaranteed to be true?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, memory-barriers, memory-model

Consider this example:

```
x = 0; // initially 0
y = 0; // initially 0

-Thread 1-                
y.store (20, memory_order_release); 
x.store (10, memory_order_release);

-Thread 2-
if (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10) {
  assert (y.load(memory_order_acquire) == 20);
  y.store (10, memory_order_release)
}

-Thread 3-
if (y.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10) {
  assert (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10);
}
```

In this example, if the `if` statement in thread3 does not execute, the assertion in thread3 won't be executed. So, we just need to consider the case when the `if` statement is executed. This means the store operation on y in thread2 that sets the value `10` should be seen by the load operation of `y` in thread3, which requires the `if` statement in thread2 execute, similar, which requires the load operation of `x` in thread2 see the value stored by the store operation of `x` in thread1. Hence, if the assertion in the thread3 is executed, we will have these conditions

> 1. x-store-in-thread1 synchronizes x-load-in-thread2
> 2. y-store-in-thread2 synchronizes y-load-in-thread3

Hence, the complete conditions we will have are:

> p1: y-store-in-thread1 is sequenced before x-store-in-thread1
>
> p2: x-store-in-thread1 synchronizes x-load-in-thread2
>
> p3: x-load-in-thread2 is sequenced before y-load-in-assert-in-thread2
>
> p4: y-load-in-assert-in-thread2 is sequenced before y-store-in-thread2
>
> p5: y-store-in-thread2 synchronizes y-load-in-thread3
>
> p6: y-load-in-thread3 is sequenced before x-load-in-thread3

With these conditions, we can further infer these conclusions:

> p2 => p2': x-store-in-thread1 inter-thread happens before x-load-in-thread2
>
> p1 + p2' => p7: y-store-in-thread1 inter-thread happens before x-load-in-thread2
>
> p2 + p3 => p8: x-store-in-thread1 inter-thread happens before y-load-in-assert-in-thread2
>
> p1 + p8 => p9: y-store-in-thread1 inter-thread happens before y-load-in-assert-in-thread2
>
> p5 => p5': y-store-in-thread2 inter-thread happens before y-load-in-thread3
>
> p4 + p5' => p10: y-load-in-assert-in-thread2 inter-thread happens before y-load-in-thread3
>
> p5 + p6 => p11: y-store-in-thread2 inter-thread happens before x-load-in-thread3
>
> p4 + p11 => p12: y-load-in-assert-in-thread2 inter-thread happens before x-load-in-thread3
>
> p3 + p12 => p13: x-load-in-thread2 inter-thread happens before x-load-in-thread3
>
> p2' + p13 => p14: x-store-in-thread1 inter-thread happens before x-load-in-thread3
>
> p14 => **x-store-in-thread1 happens before x-load-in-thread3**

Since [intro.races] p18 says:

> If a side effect X on an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, then the evaluation B shall take its value from X or from a side effect Y that follows X in the modification order of M.

In this case, we do not have a store operation of x after x-store-in-thread1, in the modification order of `x`. Hence, x-load-in-thread3 should read the value stored by x-store-in-thread1, hence, the conclusion of my analysis is the assertion in thread3 is guaranteed to be true when it is executed, in any other cases, the assertion won't be executed.

However, the Overall Summary in [GCC Atomic Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) says:

> Release/acquire mode only requires the two threads involved to be synchronized. This means that synchronized values are not commutative to other threads. The assert in thread 2 must still be true since thread 1 and 2 synchronize with x.load(). Thread 3 is not involved in this synchronization, so when thread 2 and 3 synchronize with y.load(), thread 3's assert can fail. There has been no synchronization between threads 1 and 3, **so no value can be assumed for 'x' there**.

But, I do infer that the store operation of x in thread 1 **happens before** the load operation of x in thread 3.

Comment: The whole MT semantic would be useless if acquire/release was limited to the exact opinions (or views) of the two threads; it wouldn't even make sense as no thread would be able to share its view of the world with another one!

Comment: @curiousguy What is your opinion of this example?

Comment: The chain of cause and action very clearly guarantees the condition. If not, you couldn't have more than two concurrent threads sharing data, ever (you could only have more threads as a temporary measure, but they would have to terminate before sharing data). And mutexes wouldn't work properly either.

Comment: As discussed in chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56066068#56066068), Thread 3 can only see `y==10` if thread 2 already saw `x==10`. The release and acquire operations create happens-before relationships between the threads if they see the stored values they're looking for.
And the `y.store(10, release)` happens-after the `y.store` in thread 1, so it's later in the mod order, won't get overwritten before thread 3 sees it.  So yes, you're correct, none of the asserts can fail.

Comment: I think the GCC wiki is wrong about this case, overly pessimistic.  Unlike `consume`, happens-before can connect across threads.  A sign of wrong thinking that might have lead to this conclusion is the earlier paragraph *When 2 threads synchronize in sequentially consistent mode, all the visible variables must be flushed through the system*.  All atomic stores eventually commit to cache-coherent shared memory (if you're talking in those terms).  The question is whether this thread waits for that to happen or not.

Comment: The duplicate I linked isn't a language-lawyer question, but I think the answer there is sufficiently formal to answer this here as well.

Comment: @user17732522: 100% agreed, and it's about the exact same code from the GCC wiki.

Comment: @PeterCordes Without your clarification, I would think I was misunderstanding something.